# Проблема показа междустраничных рекламных блоков InterstitialAd

Tags: android, google-adsense, ads

Поставил рекламный блок для показа при переходе в другую activity. При этом идентификаторы поставил все тестовые. Само приложение уже опубликовано, разрешение на рекламу включено. Делал все по инструкции Google.

Однако рекламный блок не показывается. В чем может быть проблема?

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_card);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.inter_bunner_Id));

        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.bunner_Id));
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ImageButton imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonHome);
        View.OnClickListener clickHome = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goHome();
            }
        };
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(clickHome);

        bookUriFromId();
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        String coverUrl = "http://*****.ru/todbook/book_"+bookId+"/pages/page1.jpg";

        Picasso.with(BookCardActivity.this)
                .load(coverUrl)
                .into(imageView);

        buttonDownload = findViewById(R.id.button);

        /**
         * Проверим наличие файлов в папке bookfiles_1, bookfiles_2, ...
         */
        String folderBook = "bookfiles_" + bookId;
        /**
         * Проверяем необходимость загрузки файлов
         */

        File rootFile1 = new File(String.valueOf(getExternalFilesDir(folderBook)));
        File[] filesArray = rootFile1.listFiles();
        int numbFiles = filesArray.length;
        if (numbFiles == 0) {

            buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonDownload);

            Thread jsDownload = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    bookLoader();
                }
            });
            jsDownload.start(); // запустили поток 1*/

            /**
             * Обрабатываем нажатие кнопки "Загрузить" и грузим файлы книги
             */

            buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

// Составляем список url для загрузки файлов. Читаем их из ранее записанного json
                    String fileListB = "list_" + "book_" + bookId + ".json";
                    String jsReadFile = MyJSON.getData(getApplicationContext(), fileListB);
//                    Log.d(TAG, jsReadFile);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Book book = gson.fromJson(jsReadFile, Book.class);
                    List<String> pages = book.getPageUrl();
                    List<String> sounds = book.getSoundUrl();
                    String[] urlsPages = pages.toArray(new String[0]);
                    String[] urlsSounds = sounds.toArray(new String[0]);
                    String[] urlsFiles = arrayAndArrayNewArray(urlsPages, urlsSounds);
// Запускаем загрузку файлов AsyncTask
                    BookFilesLoader bookFilesLoader = new BookFilesLoader();
                    bookFilesLoader.execute(urlsFiles);

                    buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            nextActivity();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            buttonDownload.setText(R.string.buttonRead);
            buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }

                    nextActivity();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Вот лог ошибок:

```
02-24 15:41:23.358 9065-9065/ru.yandex.matu1.*** I/Ads: Starting ad request.
02-24 15:41:23.358 9065-9065/ru.yandex.matu1.*** I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
02-24 15:41:23.583 9065-9079/ru.yandex.matu1.*** I/Ads: No fill from ad server.
02-24 15:41:23.583 9065-9065/ru.yandex.matu1.*** W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
```